# Analyticity of convergent series whose terms consists of powers of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine whether the statement is True or False: If $f(z)$ is an analytic function on an open set $\Omega$ and $|f(z)|<1$ on $\Omega,$ then the series $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n[f(z)]^{n}$ is analytic on $\Omega$

The series will be point wise convergent by ratio test, but how to prove the analyticity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If a sequence of analytic functions converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$, the limit is analytic on $\Omega$.  This can be proven using Morera's theorem.

Comment: How to ensure the convergence is uniform on compact subsets of $\Omega$?

Comment: on a compact set $K$ one has $|f(z)| \le M_K<1$ since $f$ is continuos so attains its maximum